# How can I read android smart phone accelerometer or gyroscope date through adb?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to get the acceleromter data from my phone through adb is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

To get for instance the accelerometer's sensor values on an Android emulator you can use `adb`'s `dumpsys` command:

```
adb shell dumpsys
```

and look for `mLastFilteredX`, `mLastFilteredY` and `mLastFilteredZ` values under the DisplayRotation/AccelSensorJudge section.

With a real device you can look at last accelerometer/gyroscope events by searching for *Accelerometer: last 50 events* (*Gyroscope: last 10 events*) on the dumpsys's output.

Comment: I tried adb shell dumpsys | grep mLastFilteredX and got nothing. Also, I tried it for other thinhs such as mLastFilteredY and mLastFilteredZ also got nothing. Whats wrong?

Comment: which Android version did you use? I tested it on API 30 (emulator)

Comment: I am using a real system. dav@dav-OptiPlex:~$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
8.1.0
dav@dav-OptiPlex:~$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
27

Comment: I tried it and I didn't get any output. 
dev@dev-OptiPlex:~$ adb shell dumpsys | grep accelerometer
Binary file (standard input) matches
dev@dev-OptiPlex:~$ adb shell dumpsys | grep gyroscope
Binary file (standard input) matches

Comment: you should try with `adb shell dumpsys | grep -i accelerometer`

Comment: dev@dev-OptiPlex:~$ adb shell dumpsys | grep -i accelerometer
Binary file (standard input) matches